# WAMP database accessible on 2 computers

Tags: database, vb6, phpmyadmin, wampserver, lan

I have a WAMP server running on my laptop and I want its database to be accessible from another laptop.

I have a VB 6.0 application which is using WAMP server (PHP_MYSQL database) and I want to let another PC or Lap Top  to access the database.

How can I configure or program VB to access the database?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. We have multiple machines connecting to our wampserver databases Here is a checklist to get your started:

- Have you [granted external access](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant.html) to your MySQL user accounts?
- Have you opened up your Windows firewall to [allow incoming connections](http://windows.microsoft.com/is-IS/windows-vista/Open-a-port-in-Windows-Firewall) to your MySQL port?
- Is your VB6 app set up to [connect to MySQL](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?633096-VB6-Remote-MySQL-connection)?